# two monitor Display using tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I have a TKinter python program which show the two GUI Window that runs just fine on one monitor, but now I want to run two full screen windows, one on each display on one monitor and another full screen window to second monitor both monitors are connected with one Raspberry Pi 4. I can't get the second windows to second monitor , both windows open on first monitor.
Kindly suggest the solution with you specialties.